# Complex function terminology question

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

Suppose that I have a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.  Representing the complex number in polar notation $z=re^{i\theta}$, I integrate the phase $\theta$ out as follows:

$$g(r)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(r,\theta)d\theta$$

Is there a name for $g(r)$?

Comment: What is $x$? Moreover, this isn't a function. The integral returns a number.

Comment: @Fantini The integral looks like a function of $r$.  Perhaps they meant to write $g(r)$?

Comment: Oh right!  Oops, yes, I meant $g(r)$ not $g(x)$.  Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you slightly modify your definition to:
$$
g(r)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(r,\theta)d\theta
$$
does that offer any suggestion?

Comment: Well, that of course would be the expectation of a $f(r,\theta)$ over uniformly distributed phase.  I was wondering if there a more "complex-theoretic" term for $g(r)$...

Comment: @M.B.M. check out the mean value property at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function.  I am assuming you mean for $f(z)$ to be analytic, of course.